# How to use jq to map values between two large keys containing related data

Tags: json, join, jq

I am doing `curl` request and getting response:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "run-12345",
      "message": "some message",
      "created-by": "me",
      "attributes": {
        "is-cancelable": false,
        "is-confirmable": false,
        "is-discardable": false,
        "is-force-cancelable": false
      },
      "relationships": {
        "configuration-version": {
          "data": {
            "id": "cv-23198",
            "type": "configuration-version"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "run-67891",
      "message": "some message",
      "created-by": "me",
      "attributes": {
        "is-cancelable": false,
        "is-confirmable": false,
        "is-discardable": false,
        "is-force-cancelable": false
      },
      "relationships": {
        "configuration-version": {
          "data": {
            "id": "cv-12198",
            "type": "configuration-version"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "included": [
    {
      "id": "cv-23198",
      "type": "ingress-attributes",
      "attributes": {
        "branch": "prod",
        "clone-url": "ssh://git@github/project/repo-awesome.git",
        "commit-message": "Commit message 1",
        "commit-sha": "4444444444444444444444f601bb4bcd5e07f02a",
        "sender-username": "Name Surname"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "cv-12198",
      "type": "ingress-attributes",
      "attributes": {
        "branch": "dev",
        "clone-url": "ssh://git@github/project/less-awesome.git",
        "commit-message": "Commit message 3",
        "commit-sha": "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee44f601bb4bcd5e07f02a",
        "sender-username": "Joe Sur"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to use `jq` to kind of iterate over key `"data"` and select important info about particular `"id"` and then some additional information related to this very `"id"` is also stored in this other main key `"included"` and it is `id`'ed via `"ww-212121"`.

Is there any way to kind of get or map data from this two sources together ?

I tried something like this but it obviously does not work

```bash
curl <http://...>| jq -r '.data[] | {"run-id": .id , message: .message, "created-by": ."created-by", cv: .relationships."configuration-version".data.id}'
{
  "run-id": "run-12345",
  "message": "some message",
  "created-by": "me",
  "cv": "cv-23198",
  "branch": "prod",
  "sender-username": "Name Surname"
}
{
  "run-id": "run-67891",
  "message": "some message",
  "created-by": "me",
  "cv": "cv-12198",
  "branch": "dev",
  "sender-username": "Joe Sur"

}
```

I cannot find a way how to enrich this jq so I will have the info about a branch and sender-username taken from keyword "included"

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.  In your case, this would mean giving a valid JSON example as input, with the corresponding expected output.

Comment: I have updated my question with a minimal example. Thx for letting me know

Comment: Trying something like this:

Also something like this does not work:

jq -r '.included as $inc | .data[] | {"run-id": .id , message: .message, "created-by": ."created-by", cv: .relationships."configuration-version".data.id, branch: $inc[] | select(.id==.relationships."configuration-version".data.id).attributes.branch }'

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after reading JQ docs many times I fond a solution to my question:

```
    cat example.json| jq -r '(.included | map({(.id): .}) | add)  as $inc | .data[] | {"run-id": .id , message: .message, "created-by": ."created-by", cv: .relationships."configuration-version".data.id, branch: $inc[.relationships."configuration-version".data.id].attributes.branch, "commit-message":$inc[.relationships."configuration-version".data.id].attributes."commit-message", "sender-username": $inc[.relationships."configuration-version".data.id].attributes."sender-username"  }'
{
  "run-id": "run-12345",
  "message": "some message",
  "created-by": "me",
  "cv": "cv-23198",
  "branch": "prod",
  "commit-message": "Commit message 1",
  "sender-username": "Name Surname"
}
{
  "run-id": "run-67891",
  "message": "some message",
  "created-by": "me",
  "cv": "cv-12198",
  "branch": "dev",
  "commit-message": "Commit message 3",
  "sender-username": "Joe Sur"
}
```

Comment: FYI, here's [the same thing with a less typing](https://jqplay.org/s/qIxl_T36MTX "link to jqplay.org -->").

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version thanks to rickhg12hs:

```
cat filtered.json | jq -r '(.included | 
  map({(.id): .}) | add) as $inc | 
  .data[] | {
    "run-id": .id, 
    "time": .attributes."status-timestamps"
  } + 
  ($inc[$inc[.relationships."configuration-version".data.id].relationships."ingress-attributes".data.id].attributes |
  {
    branch, 
    "commit-message", 
    "sender-username",
    "clone-url"
  })'
```